# How to establish a connection between a tcp client/server running in a Docker container and a tcp server/client running in an external device?

Tags: docker, networking, tcp, plc

I'm quite new to Docker, and I'm wondering how would you set-up the network for the scenario depicted in the simple diagram below.
I need to get the tcp clients and servers establishing encrypted communications, from within the docker container to the external device.
Any ideas?

UPDATE:
At the time I posted the question I didn't have much experience with Docker.

I finally realized the following:

- Outbound communications (from the containers to external devices or to the Internet): will work out of the box, with not special configuration.
- Inbound communications (from external devices to docker containers): it's necessary to open the required tcp port in every container, via the docker command (or using a docker-compose file, described in the following point).
  E.g.:

```
docker run -p <hostPort>:<containerPort> imageName
```

where containerPort is the port used inside of the container (for
example for a backend server's api) and the hostPort is the port
exposed to the user of the container (the one that will be really
used by an external application). The ports can be the same.

- Communications between containers: one option could be to use a docker-compose.yaml file, setting up a network between the containers: in this way every container can communicate with the other containers even using as hostnames (instead of an ip address) the service names configured in the docker-compose file.

Example of a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

More on docker-compose:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

this is a very general question and not a specific problem. Please see https://docs.docker.com/network/ for more information. A lot depends on the mode you choose for your docker containers, for example bridge versus host mode. Depending on that, the above will be a little different. In host mode, your dockers will be available on the host PC via the defined port, in bridge mode, you will have to map ports from the host to the docker image. Again, first study the documentation, because it's basically the answer to your question.